# Listview check/uncheck checkbox on row click

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

I want to check or uncheck my checkbox in a listview when I click on the row.

Comment: You have our permission to do so.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms and you have the ListView control's `FullRowSelect = true`, you can use the control's MouseDown event to find the clicked row:

```
void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  var lvi = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
  if (lvi != null) {
    lvi.Checked = !lvi.Checked;
  }
}
```

VB.Net:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDown
  Dim lvi = ListView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
  If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
    lvi.Checked = Not lvi.Checked
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect.

Comment: @KoenAmant Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the tag.  Updated the post with your vb.net version.